# How to load human readable JSON file into Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a big formatted json file of big schema. But each json object is not ending in line. It spans multiple lines and next json object just starts with , Then How can I read it using Pig JsonLoader(). I am getting errors for reading below file -

{"recipe":"Tacos","ingredients":[{"name":"Beef"},{"name":"Lettuce"
},{"name":"Cheese"}],"inventor":{"name":"Alex","age":25}}{"recipe":"TomatoSoup","ingredients":[{"name":"Tomatoes"},{"name":"Milk"}],"inventor":{"name":"Steve","age":23}}

FYI, I know it will work if we format it by eol style..

Answer (score 0):

the solution I use to load weird `json` files is to use Twitter's `elephantbird`

https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird